# Unauthorized HTTP request consuming simple WCF service

Tags: wcf

We are in the process of setting up a Restful WCF service per these guidelines:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor

The instructions are fine and we have successfully got our test version running and displaying XML results in the browser (in our case `Person` records).

One problem we have is the author doesn't take us much beyond displaying XML in a browser.

You'd think once the results are coming down to you in XML form it'd be really easy to knock up a client which can deserialize that data into your `Person` class.

Actually, not so easy. Lots of scratching our heads about bindings and endpoints which ... not sure we've properly mastered. Anyway, after a while, found a code sample which half way made sense and knocked this up:

```
Dim persons As Persons
Using host As New WebServiceHost(GetType(MyTestService), New Uri("http://MyServer:8443/TestService/"))
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IMyTestService), New BasicHttpBinding(), "")
    host.Open()

    Using cf As New ChannelFactory(Of IMyTestService)(New BasicHttpBinding(), "http://MyServer:8443/TestService/")
        cf.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(New WebHttpBehavior())
        Dim channel As IMyTestService = cf.CreateChannel()


        persons = channel.GetPersons
    End Using

    MsgBox(persons.Count)

End Using
```

The only problem is it's failing on the line `persons = channel.GetPersons` with this error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'.

Now, I find it strange to get an authentication error when the server is quite happy to give me the data over IE or Chrome.

So then we tried changing `WebHttpBinding` to `BasicHttpBinding` more in hope than expectation since we aren't really sure what these methods are really doing under the surface but that produces an error:

> The endpoint at 'http://MyServer:8443/TestService/' does not have a
>   Binding with the None MessageVersion. 
>   'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior' is only intended for
>   use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... that code sample you're showing would be the **server** side of a WCF service using the `basicHttpBinding` which is a **SOAP** binding and has nothing to do with REST... It's **definitely not** code for a client to a WCF REST service!

Assuming your WCF REST service is up and running, your client would be something rather simple, like this:

```
// create a new web request to query your service
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://MyServer:8443/TestService/");

// get the response
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

// examine some properties of the response
long length = response.ContentLength;
string contentType = response.ContentType;

// fetch the XML (or JSON) contents of the response
string content = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: I've got it up and running now. Thanks for your time. You 100K+ rep users are the Olympic gold medallists of StackOverflow. I still don't get the binding and endpoint stuff but maybe I don't have to.

Comment: I _did_ got a 401 unauthorized request situation but figured that out using other StackOverflow answers. Thanks again.